# Celery / Flask update_state not changing state

Tags: python, celery

My flask config looks like this

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0"    
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0"    
CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0"    
BROKER_URL = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0"    
RESULT_BACKEND = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0"    
CACHE_BACKEND = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0"
```

I've got so many as I'm really not sure if I should be doing the prefix CELERY_ or not or if i need the CACHE_BACKEND at all.

```
@celery.task(bind=True, name="apptask")
def apptask(self, oi):
    for x in range(40):
        sleep(1)
        self.update_state("Running", meta={"test":1, "val": oi})
    return current_app.name
```

This is my celery task

And this is the route that calls the task.

```
@users.route("/test", methods=["GET"])
def test():

    task = apptask.apply_async(args=["d"])
    ts = apptask.AsyncResult(task.id)
    print(ts.info)
    print(ts.status)
```

Celery is running and picks up the task call, the task executes and suceeds but I can never get to the meta data and the status doesn't appear to update with my custom state.

Status is anyways "PENDING" or "SUCCESS" and never "RUNNING" also `ts.info` is None.

Does anyone know why this might be? Am I missing a config, has something been set up wrong etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realised I missed out the kwarg `state` from the update_state call. Which must have been throwing an error or having unintended side effects.

`self.update_state(state="Running", meta={"test":1, "val": oi})`

This has fixed it.